# Why does a positive lookahead lead to captures in my Perl regex?

Tags: perl, matching, regex-lookarounds

I can't get why this code work:

```
$seq = 'GAGAGAGA';
my $regexp = '(?=((G[UCGA][GA]A)|(U[GA]CG)|(CUUG)))'; # zero width match
while ($seq =~ /$regexp/g){ # globally
     my $pos = pos($seq) + 1; # position of a zero width matching
     print "$1 position $pos\n";
}
```

I know this is a zero width match and it dosn't put the matched string in $&, but why does it put it in $1?

thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Matches are captured in `$1` because of all the internal parentheses. If you don't want capturing, then use

```
my $regexp = '(?=(?:(?:G[UCGA][GA]A)|(?:U[GA]CG)|(?:CUUG)))';
```

or even better

```
my $regexp = qr/(?=(?:(?:G[UCGA][GA]A)|(?:U[GA]CG)|(?:CUUG)))/;
```

From the [perlre documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3f%3apattern)):

> - `(?:pattern)`
> - `(?imsx-imsx:pattern)`
>
> This is for clustering, not capturing; it groups subexpressions like `()`, but doesn't make backreferences as `()` does. So
>
> ```
> @fields = split(/\b(?:a|b|c)\b/)
> ```
>
> is like
>
> ```
> @fields = split(/\b(a|b|c)\b/)
> ```
>
> but doesn't spit out extra fields. It's also cheaper not to capture characters if you don't need to.
>
> Any letters between `?` and `:` act as flags modifiers as with `(?imsx-imsx)`. For example,
>
> ```
> /(?s-i:more.*than).*million/i
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the more verbose
>
> ```
> /(?:(?s-i)more.*than).*million/i
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression contains a capture `(...)` which means the `$1`, `$2`, etc. variables will be populated with the results of those captures. This works in lookahead assertions too (although not lookbehind assertions, I believe).

As with all captures, if you rewrite as `(?:...)` then the contents will not go into a capture variable.